# startMonitoringForRegion not working, though implemented properly

Tags: ios, core-location, geofencing

I've been trying to get geofencing working, but it doesn't seem to be happening.

I'm getting the didStartMonitoringForRegion delegate method, but didEnterRegion and didExitRegion don't get called when they should. I can get didExitRegion to fire if I set the simulator to 1000's of km away, but obviously that's not going to be accurate enough.

I figured I must have implemented it incorrectly, so I downloaded the source files from this tutorial:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/geofencing-with-core-location--mobile-15477

However, I get the exact same behaviour (didStartMonitoringForRegion fires when implemented, but enter/exit do not), which makes me think my issue isn't with the code. I've tried it both in the simulator and on an actual device while driving around and it doesn't work.

I can't figure out what I'm missing!

Comment: do you have background app refresh enabled in your device's settings? Another reason of failure is cllocation manager's delegate, make sure you have the location manager's delegate set where you implement did enter/did exit.

Comment: or just double check your CLRegion. if you never go from inside to outside or reverse, you'll never be inform about that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should implement this delegate in your Class where you are adding the regions:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error
```

So you can know if a location failed to register (maybe because you provided invalid coordinates, or you exceeded the maximum number of regions your app can register).

Second, when you test it on the simulator you need to use a GPX file, to simulate you moving towards a region, and not just change the simulator location.

Here is an example gpx file for walking towards the center of Manhattan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx>
    <wpt lat="40.737181" lon="-73.98"></wpt>
    <wpt lat="40.733604" lon="-73.992110"></wpt>
</gpx>
```

It will start slowly giving the simulator location updates from way point 1 to waypoint 2.

Your waypoint 1 should be a couple of miles outside the region you are monitoring and waypoint 2 ideally should be in the center of it.
You can also add a 3rd waypoint, outside the region, so you can get the exit notification again.

This will not work instantly as the simulator simulates driving/walking from waypoint to waypoint. You will need to wait a couple of seconds to get a notification.

Finally just as a hint, you need to check if your desired radius exceeds the maximum allowed radius from the OS, here is my implementation to add regions for monitoring:

```
- (void)registerRegionWithenterPoint:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)centerPoint regionRadius:(CLLocationDistance)radius andIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier {

    // If the radius is too large, registration fails automatically,
    // so clamp the radius to the max value.    
    if (radius > self.locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance)
        radius = self.locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance;

    // Create the region and start monitoring it.
    CLRegion* region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centerPoint radius:radius identifier:identifier];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:(kSystemVersion>=6)?400:100];
}
```

The constant `kSystemVersion` is just a constant with the iOS version, as Apple suggests using different accuracy levels depending on the OS version.

Try my suggestions and see if you get any updates, but if not, please post your whole code for region monitoring as you might be doing something wrong, which from what you just say I cannot detect